# php variable value in a while loop for each row

Tags: php, database, while-loop, sql-update

I have a cancel button on each row of a table that is autopopulated in a while loop.
The $id resolves correctly but when I click on the cancel button all the active rows are modified. I only want the row that is concerned to be modified.

So in a while loop in php:

```
          <tr id="dataTable">
        <td id="nom"><?php echo $nom;?></td>

          <td id="statut"><?php echo $statut;?> </td>
        <td id="<?php echo $id;?>" >

            <a id="<?php echo $id;?>"  href="#" title="Annuler"   
             onclick="document.write('<?php              
              $queryannuler = "UPDATE wp_RDV SET statut = 'Testy' WHERE id_RDV = '".$id."'";
              $resultatannuler = $connexion->query($queryannuler); ?>'); location.reload(); 'return false';">Annuler</a>

        </td>
      </tr>
```

My problem is the 'statut' column is being updated for all the rows and not just the row where I click on the cancel button. Thanks if you can help.

**UPDATE**
I have tried to implement your different advices by using ajax. It's tough. I didn't specify in the original post that I am using a Wordpress framework. So I have modified @ssurli code to take into account wordpress

```
   <td id="<?php echo $id;?>" >
   <a id="<?php echo $id;?>" class="button delete"  href="javascript:void(0)" title="Annuler"   
   onclick="cancelRecord('<?php echo $id; ?>')">Annuler</a>
   </td>

<script>
function cancelRecord(id) {
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: ajaxurl, 
    data: {id:id},
    action: 'delete_rdv',
    success: function(response) {
        return;
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {
        alert('Error: Please refresh the page');
        return;
    },
    complete: function() {
        console.log('The function is hooked up');
        location.reload();
        console.log('The function is hooked up2');
    }
});
```

}

AND in my functions.php file

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_delete_rdv', 'delete_rdv' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_delete_rdv', 'delete_rdv' );

function delete_rdv() {
$queryannuler = "UPDATE wp_RDV SET statut = 'Testy' WHERE id_RDV = '".$_POST['id']."'";
$resultatannuler = $connexion->query($queryannuler);  //include connection file above
return $resultatannuler;
}
```

I'm stuck on the very first hurdle. 
The console is sending an error message : 
    admin.php?page=plugin-voc:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: cancelRecord is not defined

But my **cancelRecord** function is right after my button call so I don't understand this error.

Comment: Your question needs more focus. You should first have a look at how ajax calls work. Either visit http://w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp or use a library like http://jquery.com to perform the ajax call that will perform the cancellation. If you still have a problem then with the ajax call ask again and we will help you

Comment: Maybe I mislead you in using the word "cancel". All this button does is change the text in one of the database's column. I just don't understand why it is changing the text in multiple rows and not just the concerned row. Do I really need ajax to do that?

Comment: You want to execute php code (on the server) when a JavaScript event happens (on the browser). Have a look at ajax and you'll see how it is the way to go. You can't execute code on the server from javascript the way you tried

Comment: The reason for the error is that you're updating the values when you RENDER the page, NOT when the button is clicked. Test it out, load the page but don't click anything. Even if you don't want to deal with AJAX, you need REST at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the original html request

```
    <td id="<?php echo $id;?>" >
<a id="<?php echo $id;?>" class="button delete"  href="javascript:void(0)" title="Annuler"   
onclick="cancelRecord('<?php echo $id; ?>')">Annuler</a>
```

The javascript function was not defined when I put it in the same file as the php. I moved into the plugin index.js file and most importantly I moved this line:

```
action: 'delete_rdv',
```

into data {}

```
data: {
        action: 'delete_rdv',
        id:id},
```

Here is the complete javascript code:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($){ $('.button.delete').on('click', function(){ let id = $(this).attr('id'); cancelRecord(id); }); });

function cancelRecord(id) {
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: ajaxurl, 
    data: {
        action: 'delete_rdv',
        id:id},

    success: function(response) {
        return;
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {
        alert('Error: Please refresh the page');
        return;
    },
    complete: function() {
        location.reload();
    }
});
}
```

The ajax calls the function delete_rdv which I put in the functions.php file

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_delete_rdv', 'delete_rdv' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_delete_rdv', 'delete_rdv' );

function delete_rdv() {
$queryannuler = "UPDATE wp_RDV SET statut = 'Annulé' WHERE id_RDV = '".$_POST['id']."'";
$resultatannuler = $connexion->query($queryannuler);  //include connection file above
return $resultatannuler;
}
```

Special thanks to @jeprubio for kinda forcing to look the ajax way and to @sssurii for posting his code and answering my question.

Answer (score 1):

Here the working code.

Update your table row as below:

```
<tr id="dataTable">
    <td id="nom"><?php echo $nom;?></td>
    <td id="statut"><?php echo $statut;?> </td>
    <td id="<?php echo $id;?>" >
    <a id="<?php echo $id;?>"  href="javascript:void(0)" title="Annuler"   
     onclick="cancelRecord('<?php echo $id; ?>')">Annuler</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Add below js scripts to bottom of your html page. Include jquery cdn file only if not add to page already.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
function cancelRecord(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'cancel.php', //use actual directory path, if not kept in root directory
        data: {id:id},
        success: function(response) {
            return;
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {
            alert('Error: Please refresh the page');
            return;
        },
        complete: function() {
            location.reload();
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Add PHP file having PHP code having DB query responsible for cancelling the record.
//cancel.php

```
<?php              
$queryannuler = "UPDATE wp_RDV SET statut = 'Testy' WHERE id_RDV = '".$_POST['id']."'";
$resultatannuler = $connexion->query($queryannuler);  //include connection file above
return $resultatannuler;
```

Hope it will work for you. Feel free if you have any further query.

Comment: Hi, could you take a look at my new code and give me your opinion why it's not working please

Comment: To resolve console error, you can bind click event on document ready. add below code to script:
`jQuery( document ).ready(function($){
    $('.button.delete').on('click', function(){
     let id = $(this).attr('id');
     cancelRecord(id);
 });
});`

Comment: I tried this code, within and before the function but it did not work. I have a feeling the error is coming from this part: admin.php?page=plugin-voc:1. I must look into what is **plugin-voc**. Thanks @sssurii for helping. I'll let you know